# Has the default rounding in Mathematica changed?

Tags: floating-point, rounding, wolfram-mathematica

I am using Mathematica 13.3. If I enter

```
43782.92 + 23.99
```

the output returned is 43806.9 instead of 43806.91. Is this rounding/floating-point arithmetic behavior typical for Mathematica? I think I have never came across it before. If I instead enter `3782.92 + 23.99`

I get the correct answer 3806.91. Any thoughts?

Many thanks!

I expected to receive 43806.91. The Calculator app on my mac returns the correct sum.

Comment: Is the default display to show six significant digits? What do you get when you ask Mathematica to show the full value? What do you get when you subtract 43806.9?

Comment: You might have better luck asking on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh, it is the 6 digits causing it?! The difference is indeed 0.01. Thanks!